# There is an error when i use kinect v1 with Mrpt tool

Tags: mobile-robot

when i use mrpt tool to calibrate kinect v1, there is an error:

```
skydddive@ding-turtlebot:/usr/bin$ ./kinect-stereo-calib

Could no claim interface on camera: -6
Calling CKinect::initialize()...Exception in Kinect thread:

=================MRPT EXCEPTION ====================
void mrpt::hwdrivers::CKinect::open(),line 399:
Error opening Kinect sensor with index :0
```

please give me some advice to solve this problem,thank you~~

Comment: Perhaps your program is trying to open the usb port that is mapped to index 0, but there is no kinect connected to that port?

Comment: Could also be that the right drivers are not installed on the processing platform for the kinect to work via usb.